# Javascript Date Validation

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How to validate particular format date string using Javascript? 
I have one date picker which has the display format like "dddd MMMM dd, yyyy"(displaying like this:"Wednesday February 03, 2010".) So i have to validate this format using javascript. Please help me for implementing this..

Comment: Have you tried searching the web for pages relating to validating dates using javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check *exactly* that format, you could use regular expression:

```
var re = new RegExp( '^(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)\\s*(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|November|December)\\s*(\\d\\d),\\s*(\\d{2,4})$' );

var date = 'Wednesday February 03, 2010';
if ( ( match = date.match( re ) ) != null )
{ // valid
    alert( match );
}
```

Or if you just need to know if it is a valid date, what format ever, simply convert it:

```
var dateSec, dateObj, dateStr = 'Wednesday February 03, 2010';
dateSec = Date.parse( dateStr ); // unix timestamp
if ( dateSec ) // not NaN
   dateObj = new Date( dateSec ); // date object
```

Answer (score 3):

If your application is going to require date manipulation methods, you may want to consider using something like the [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library.

If you opt for Datejs, you can use the [parseExact()](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact) method for the validation. It will return a date object if the date is valid, or null if the date is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Native JavaScript support for date formatting and validation is somewhat limited.

Take a look at http://www.datejs.com/

You can do stuff like Date.parse('my date string')

Answer (score 0):

Datejs or Dojo can do this. With [dojo.date.locale.parse](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dojo.date.locale.parse):

```
var dateAsString = "Wednesday February 03, 2010";
var dateObject = dojo.date.locale.parse(dateAsString, {datePattern: "EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy", selector: "date", locale: "en"});
```

dateObject will contain the Date object, or null if the string does not match the specified pattern.  This can work with a fixed language or any native language.

It doesn't seem right that a date picker would use this as a serialized Date format, though.  It should use something easier to parse, like [ISO8601 representation](http://www.iso.org/iso/date_and_time_format).